# Linq when joining no records return

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get articles by publishers who are members or employees and trying to use the following query:

```
var articles = context.articles
    .Include("Article")
    .Include("ArticleType")
    .Include("Language")
    .Join(
        context.publishers
        , cb => cb.publisher_id.ToString()
        , ct => ct.id
        , (cb, ct) =>
            new
            {
                articles = cb
                ,
                publishers = ct
            }
        )
    .Where(
        c.articles.active != null &&
        c.articles.active.Value &&
        (
            (c.publishers.PublisherTypeId == (int)Utility.PublisherTypes.MEMBERS)
            ||
            (c.publishers.PublisherTypeId == (int)Utility.PublisherTypes.EMPLOYEES)
        )
    )
    .Select(joined => joined.articles)
    .ToList();
```

articles has a publisher_id that is a guid but publisher has a id that is a string (I did not design the database but to me this looks wrong and should be re designed).

Somehow when joining publishers no records are returned; the list is empty. I do not know why this would be since there are articles published

Comment: have you checked the case-sensivity? GUID converted to string may have different case with the id string.

Comment: Is this entity framework?  If the database field is varchar(36), you can still map it to a guid property.

Comment: @Kinetic Thank you for your reply; it's [nvarchar](max). I'm not a dba but looking at this db design I'm starting to think that an adopted puppy from the animal shelter could do a better job :-)

Comment: @Hopeless It turned out I joined on the wrong value, someone did not get the memo on table and field names I guess: https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Feb/16/sql-naming-conventions/#foreign-keys